# How to verify user Pay Pal address in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I've created a project in Laravel 5. After registering in my project, users should input their Pay Pal address. It's need to be verified. Can anyone tell me, How can I do that? Thank you....

Comment: google verify paypal address

Comment: Do it like any other email verification where you send an email to the address and have them click a link to verify it.

Comment: I need to know, weather there is such user in pay pal or not....